# mod_wsgi 2.5 on Ubuntu 9.04 with Python 2.6.2 installation

Tags: python, compiler-construction, ubuntu, mod-wsgi, wsgi

Has anybody succeeded with mod_wsgi 2.5 on Ubuntu 9.04 with default Python installation (2.6.2)?

I got compilation errors:

```
mod_wsgi.c:119:2: error: #error Sorry, mod_wsgi requires at least Python 2.3.0.
mod_wsgi.c:123:2: error: #error Sorry, mod_wsgi requires that Python supporting thread.
```

**which Python** gives /usr/bin/python and **/usr/bin/python -V** returns Python 2.6.2 so I'm not sure what's wrong with the 1st one, and honestly I don't know how to check options used in compiling default Python on Ubuntu.

There are a lot of other errors but those 2 looks most relevant.

What else could be possibly wrong??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your errors I see that you're having to compile python extensions.  If you haven't already, I suggest you install the python-dev package because it's usually required for compiling python extensions and it's not part of the default installation.

Installing the package is as easy as running:

> sudo apt-get install python-dev

from a command line.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the user that the server is running as does not have /usr/bin on its path, and there is another version of python somewhere else on the path that is < 2.3

Try:

```
which -a python
```

to find all of the pythons on your path. Perhaps one of these is what the server is running.

Comment: It's something else:

$ which -a python
/usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/X11/python
$ /usr/bin/X11/python -V
Python 2.6.2

I just got a suggestion on IRC that apt-get install python2.6-dev should resolve my problem.

Another suggestion, more clean looking, is to install libapache2-mod-wsgi.